# how to deal with animations in android

Tags: android, animation, bitmap

I am starting to make my first game in Android. It's going to be a simple 2D game, and just to make sure that I am doing the things right, I would like to ask to more experienced game developers out there:

How should I keep the animations (consisting in a succesion of bitmaps) ? Should I create a big bitmap containing all the frames, and then cut the one that I want to show on the screen at one particular time? or should I create individual files for each frame ? or is it there any other (better) way ?

Thanks